# Python object and its elements

Tags: python, oop

I am studying the codes written by other.
I think the owner wrote it using **OOP**.
when I print the results object `sims`
the output is something like below:

`[<WorldCupSim.WorldCupSim object at 0x0000018DC471B908>, <WorldCupSim.WorldCupSim object at 0x0000018DC471B5C0>]`

Number of objects in `sims` depends on number of iterations.
in this case, I run used two iterations.

I want to print the elements of the object **sims**.
It seems like I need to give more details about it.
Please advise me what are the other info to be provided.
I am confused with the codes.

Thanks
Zep

Comment: Could you please put in the code to the class that you are trying to print out, most creators normally put in a getter method that can be used to get the items inside the object

Comment: You can call `dir(sims[0])` to find out the public methods and attributes of the objects in question.

Comment: Thanks DyZ.
When i print `dir(sims[0])`.
IT print out the following items:
" ['KnockOut', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slotnames__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'group_names', 'groups', 'runsim', 'teams', 'verbose']"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a default representation of the list `sims`. If you do

```
print(sims[0])
```

then, if `WorldCupSim.WorldCupSim` has defined a string representation (which is what `print()` will show you) then you should see more useful stuff.

Comment: Thanks. What I wanted to do is to extract the data from those objects and to create a data frame. Once I can extract the data from object, i can create a dataframe. I do not know how to extract data from object. Thank you BoarGuides

Comment: Extract it like this: `sims[0].group_names`

Answer (score 2):

As per your code what I am seeing is `sims` is `array of objects`. You can use for loop to iterate your array. Below is the sample snippet

```
for o in sims:
  print(o)
```

It will print all the objects inside `sims` variable